# su- no password entry for user? installing powerline with pip

Tags: linux, passwords, sudo, pip

I am trying to install Powerline using pip to do the installation. I'm installing in to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline using the su -c "pip install github******" and get the response no password entry for user. Can someone explain?
as a side note, having spent a few hours now messing about with Powerline installation, Vim,bash,tmux does anyone have any straight forward install tips.

Comment: What happens if you su to root to get a shell prompt and then run the install script?

Comment: BTW, please define the OS, version, and distribution for all of us.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.4 lts.

Comment: hi, Im using bash to grab Powerline from Github and pip insall it. I'm new to Linux so you'll have to explain, if you don't mind. I thought i was root, name@machine. I've tried two approaches to no avail. First Vundle, which though it says it has installed doesn't show the powerline. i added the rtp, manually directed at the powerline bindings, all no good. second attempt i've found two options a python2.7 powerline pip install, which says to insatll in the usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ or a local in .local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. which doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu by default has no password for root. There are some perfectly reasonable security reasons behind this practice, see, for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root).

Instead of `su(1)` use `sudo(1)`. In your case it might be good idea to get an interactive root-shell with `sudo -i` first and then continue with whatever you are doing with pip.